# Wireless Logitech mouse scrolls 0 or 2 times in ratchet mode

Tags: mouse, logitech, libinput

I have observed a weird scrolling issue with two Logitech mice (MX Master 3 and Marathon M705): After some time in *ratchet* mode, scrolling one step up or down is sometimes registered as 0 or 2 steps (while scrolling, the point were a new scroll event is triggered *moves*, until none / two scrolls are *between* one ratchet click).

Disabling `REL_HWHEEL_HI_RES` as suggested [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-high-resolution-scroll-wheel-support-for-a-mouse-4175704498/#7) does improve it but the issue still persists (I tried different PCs, distros, DE and a Bluetooth connection for the MX 3 without success).

Using the mice on Windows works just fine so I doubt that it is some kind of hardware error. Watching the output of `sudo libinput debug-events | grep SCROLL` with `REL_HWHEEL_HI_RES` enabled reveals that the events from one ratchet scroll sum-up in a range from `105*` up to `135*` while it should be `120*`:

```
$ sudo libinput debug-events | grep SCROLL
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +1.662s       vert 7.50/60.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +1.670s       vert 1.88/15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +1.678s       vert 1.88/15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +1.688s       vert 1.88/15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel) # first scroll is 105*
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +4.140s       vert -7.50/-60.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +4.148s       vert -5.62/-45.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +4.156s       vert -3.75/-30.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel) # second scroll is -135*
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +6.714s       vert 7.50/60.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +6.722s       vert 1.88/15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +6.730s       vert 1.88/15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +6.738s       vert 1.88/15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +6.746s       vert 3.75/30.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel) # third scroll is 135* too
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +26.460s      vert -7.50/-60.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +26.468s      vert -3.75/-30.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +26.476s      vert -1.88/-15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel)
 event20  POINTER_SCROLL_WHEEL    +26.484s      vert -1.88/-15.0* horiz 0.00/0.0 (wheel) # fourth scroll is -120*
```

Now we have scrolled `-15*` (`105-135+135-120`) to far (only noticeable when this *drift* becomes `> 120*` resulting in an additional scroll?)

Is there some way to fine-adjust or filter the scrolling before it is received by `libinput`?

As a workaround I can disable the `ratchet mode` (via the mouse button or e.g Solaar) but this is obviously not a real solution.

Comment: I have experienced the same behavior with the M705. From time to time. So far, I couldn't deduce a pattern when this happens.

Comment: Related: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/889